# Checking whether a template argument is of a class type?

Tags: c++, templates

How to check using some template hack whether a template argument passed is of class type?

Example

```
int main()
{
   CheckIfClass<int>::checkConst ; No it is not of a class type
   class CLASS{};
   CheckIfClass<CLASS>::checkConst ; Yes CLASS is a class.
   CheckIfClass<std::string>::checkConst ; Yes std::string is a class
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to know?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[SFINAE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) should do your job

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type
{
    template<typename C> static char func (char C::*p);
    template<typename C> static int func (...);
    enum{val = sizeof (Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<T>::template func<T>(0)) == 1};
};
class empty{}; // Defined the class in the global namespace. 
               // You can't have local classes as template arguments in C++03

int main()
{

    std::cout<<Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<empty>::val; // 1
    std::cout<<Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<int>::val; // 0
    std::cout<<Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<std::string>::val; //1
}
```

[Output](http://ideone.com/Q599N)

```
101
```

Comment: @UpVoter : Oh ideone compiled the code in c++0x mode. Updated my answer (for C++03).

Comment: Wow! I need to figure out how the code is actually working. thanks.

Comment: @Nawaz : Yes it is optional :-)

Comment: @Prasoon Saurav... your code doesn't compile with MSVC++2008. What's wrong with it? 
    `'char Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<T>::func(char C::* )' : could   not deduce template argument for 'char C::* ' from 'int'
'int Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<T>::func(...)' : could not deduce template argument for 'C'`

Comment: @Nawaz : The code gets compiled on Comeau, g++ and Clang. MSVC++ as we all know is buggy. You can create another thread asking for an explanation why this doesn't get compiled on MSVC++. There are so many MS guys out there. :-)

Comment: @Nawaz: It would seem to compile if you remove `Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<T>::template` (should be superfluous anyway?)

Comment: @UncleBens... yeah I was trying to do those sort of things and eventually discovered it gets compiled if I remove `template` ketyword. I've posted the solution!

Answer (score 2):

C++0x offers a very simple solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    std::cout << is_class< your_type_here >::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Code that compiles with MSVC++08 ALSO, as well as with GCC, Comeau, and Clang (edited).

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename T>
struct Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type
{
    template<typename C> static char func (char C::*p);
    template<typename C> static int func (...);
    enum{val = sizeof (func<T>(0)) == 1};
};
class empty{};
int main()
{   
    std::cout<<Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<empty>::val; // 1
    std::cout<<Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<int>::val; // 0
    std::cout<<Check_If_T_Is_Class_Type<std::string>::val; //1
}
```

**@Prasoon**... could you please compile this on Comeau, and Clang ... and tell me if it gets compiled or not? thanks!

Comment: Yes it gets compiled on those :-)