# Checking whether a template argument has a member function

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a function's existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence)

This is very similar to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4352278/checking-whether-a-template-argument-is-of-a-class-type). I want to check whether a template argument contains a member function or not.

I tried this code similar to that in the accepted answer in my previous question.

```
struct A
{
   int member_func();
};

struct B
{
};

template<typename T>
struct has_member_func
{
   template<typename C> static char func(???); //what should I put in place of '???'
   template<typename C> static int func(...);

   enum{val = sizeof(func<T>(0)) == 1};
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<< has_member_func<B>::val; //should output 0
    std::cout<< has_member_func<A>::val; //should output 1
}
```

But I have no idea what should I put in place of `???` to make it work.
I am new to SFINAE concept.

Comment: Use something similar to HAS_MEM_FUNC which Johannes posted in that thread. I've used that code before and it works fine.

Comment: icecrime Thanks for pointing out that this is a duplicate. However the accepted answer uses non-standard typeof operator. Can you suggest an alternative? According to MSalter's comment static char func(char[sizeof(&C::helloworld)]) should work?

Comment: @NEWBIE: see Johannes answer, it's much better

Comment: icecrime sorry but his solution is too convoluted. can you suggest something similar to the accepted solution in the original link?

Comment: @NEWBIE : Check out @FireAphis's answer. It is much simpler than Johannes's answer. :)

Comment: @Prasoon the changes he made introduce two problems: `TypeHasToString` may fail to compile with non-class types (it won't use SFINAE when an error occurs inside `ToString<>`), and it will fail if `sizeof(char) == sizeof(long)`. I will change my answer to use typedefs so it's more readable, though.

Comment: @NEWBIE, this *is* a complicated topic for which there most probably isn't an easy solution. If this stuff is too convoluted for you, maybe that's a sign you shouldn't use it, but trying to solve the problem another way.

Answer (score 1):

Little modification of MSalters' idea from [Is it possible to write a C++ template to check for a functions existence?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/257288/is-it-possible-to-write-a-c-template-to-check-for-a-functions-existence) :

```
template<typename T>
class has_member_func
{
        typedef char no;
        typedef char yes[2];
        template<class C> static yes& test(char (*)[sizeof(&C::member_func)]);
        template<class C> static no& test(...);
public:
        enum{value = sizeof(test<T>(0)) == sizeof(yes&)};
};
```

Comment: I get this error with GCC 4.2.1:
`In instantiation of ‘has_member_func<Duck>’:`
`error: array bound is not an integer constant`