# Container-agnostic iterator parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator

How does one write a function in C++ that takes in as a parameter an iterator of a certain type in a container-agnostic way?  i.e.

```
// C# version
void foo(IEnumerable<MyConcreteClass> t)
{
   foreach(MyConcreteClass c in t)
   {
     c.MyFunction();
   }
}
```

Reading about iterators it seems I'm supposed to do something like this:

```
template<MyIter>
void foo(MyIter start, MyIter end, std::input_iterator_tag type)
{
  // How would the next part work?  Do I do:
  while (start != end)
  {
    MyConcreteClass* c = *start; // this will compile iff the parameter is correct.
    c->MyFunction();
    start++;
}
```

In the case of an invalid iterator type being passed in (e.g. a `std::unordered_set<MyOtherClass*>::iterator`), I feel that the compiler error generated using this method would just be some sort of invalid cast error at the line where I dereference `start`; I'd like instead to get an error that I'm actually passing in an iterator of the wrong type.  Is there a better way to do this?  I'd be nice to say "MyIter must be an iterator from a container of MyConcreteClass"

BTW, C++11 mechanisms are OK.

Comment: You don't have to have the `input_iterator_tag`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want, you can add something like

```
static_assert(std::is_convertible<decltype(*start), MyConcreteClass*>::value, "MyIter must be an iterator from a container of MyConcreteClass");
```

to anywhere inside the body of the function.

Be aware that this tightly couples `MyConcreteClass` and `foo`, so if you're sure you want that then it's fine. But if you don't, you can genericize it more and write

```
template<MyIter>
void foo(MyIter start, MyIter end)
{
  while (start != end) {
    auto c = *start;
    c->MyFunction();
    // Or instead of the above two statements:
    // (*c)->MyFunction(); 
    start++;
  }
}
```

This will work for a pointer to any type that has a `MyFunction` function, so now you could even use containers of `unique_ptr`s, whereas you couldn't before. But, you can't as easily write the assert statement for this one, so it's a tradeoff. The tradition of C++ is just to document the function (e.g. "This function works for all types that have a `MyFunction()` available behind an `operator->`") and let the compiler error if they violate the requirement.

Comment: +1. For the second solution, you could also develop a `static_assert`-based test (to get nicer error messages) using a compile-time test for the existence of a member function like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4354498/777186

Comment: Just to clarify, I want the tight coupling -- a better example would be like `XmlDocument` and `XmlNode`.  If, in C#, `XMLDocument` has a method like `AddChildren(IEnumerable<XmlNode> nodes)`.  Let's say I'm writing an `XmlDocument` class in C++ -- I would write that method like you suggest, with `static_assert`?

Comment: @atanamir yes, if clients can hold their `XmlNode`s in their own containers, then you would write your original version with the added `static_assert`.

Answer (score 2):

For your function, you may use something like:

```
template <template <typename...> class Container>
void foo(Container<MyConcreteClass>& container)
{
   for (auto elem : container)
   {
     elem.MyFunction();
   }
}
```

A more complete example fore extra parameter *after*:
You may use similar to work for parameter *before*

```
template <template <typename...> class Container, typename... Ts>
void foo(Container<MyConcreteClass, Ts...>& container)
{
   for (auto elem : container)
   {
     elem.MyFunction();
   }
}
```

If you use both (before and after), it may be seen as ambiguous (my gcc fails to compile).

Comment: That looks really nice.  Is that a variadic template?

Comment: Would this still work if the container type isn't the first template argument of whatever container class is being passed in?  e.g. `MyContainer<MyComparer, MyConcreteClass>`

Comment: I use variadic template because some template class take extra parameter (allocator, comparer, ...). My solution need adaptation to work with extra parameter, (I try with parameter before and after, but my compilo crashes, as ideone :-/).